# Multi search sql query

Tags: sql, hsqldb

This is a conceptual question. I am using `hsqldb` I want to create a multisearch with several different dropdown menues. My idea is to Select all and filter through where the properties I need for my query. However, that does not work as I would like to do:

For example.:

`Select distinct person, city, gender from test where person = 'John' and gender = * and city = *;`

For example.:

I have 3 columns in my table `test`: `Person, City, Gender`

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| Person |  City  | Gender |
+--------+--------+--------+
| John   | Berlin | male   |
| John   | London | male   |
| Fred   | Berlin | male   |
| Sarah  | Vienna | fem    |
| John   | London | male   |
| Fred   | Vienna | fem    |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

Now if I select in Person John I have:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| Person |  City  | Gender |
+--------+--------+--------+
| John   | Berlin | male   |
|        |        |        |
|        |        |        |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

Another example if I select Vienna in my dropdown I get:

```
+-------------------------+
| Person   City   Gender  |
+-------------------------+
| Sarah   Vienna  fem     |
| Fred                    |
+-------------------------+
```

I really would like to implement that into an sql query, because I think that would be the most elegant solution. Any recommendations how to do that? How would such a query look like?

I appreciate your answers!

**UPDATE**

OK got an idea.

I would like to implement it like that:

So when I select John I return:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| Person |  City  | Gender |
+--------+--------+--------+
| John   | Berlin | male   |
| John   | London | male   |
| John   | London | male   |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

The query would look like that I guess:

```
SELECT person, city, gender FROM test where person = 'John' and city = * and gender = *
```

At `gender = *` I get an error. What would be the best to fill in for gender and city?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: You won't be able to achieve this using a plain SQL query. You may want to consider using dynamic query or a procedure

Comment: @Thx for your answer! What do you mean by dynamic queries?

Comment: @C.J. Please have a look at my update. Will use the select for filtering and later code up a method to distinct the values. However, how should the select look like? I really appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your prepared sql statement should contain language like this:

```
...where person like ':person' and city like ':city' and gender like ':gender';
```

If you wanted a particular person by name, pass the name you're looking for and '%' for both city and gender. Whichever field you want ignored, just use '%' as the string parameter.